# SQL Server: same table, multiple names

Tags: sql-server

I have some SQL Server database tables that need to be renamed.

Unfortunately, those tables are used by some libraries for which I have no source code.

I plan to rewrite those libraries, but it will take some time.

In the meantime I wonder if there's a way to create an "alias" for my tables, so that they can be referenced with two different names.

I could create views like `SELECT * FROM OldName` but I'm concerned about performance.

Comment: So you answered 20 seconds after I posted my question... with a complete example... and you made me discover something I was completely unaware of... THANK YOU!!!

Comment: I think you wanted this comment under one of the answers, not the question. :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Create a `SYNONYM` for the old name, after you rename the table. In short:

```sql
--Create example table
CREATE TABLE dbo.YourTable (ID int); 
GO
--Rename it
EXEC sys.sp_rename N'dbo.YourTable',N'MyTable';
GO
--Create a synonym for the new name, with the old name
CREATE SYNONYM dbo.YourTable FOR dbo.MyTable;
GO
--Try selecting from old name, it works!
SELECT *
FROM YourTable;
GO
--Clean up
DROP SYNONYM dbo.YourTable;
GO

DROP TABLE dbo.MyTable;
```

Answer (score 1):

A view should cause no performance problem, as the query is converted by SQL. But synonyms are a nice option as well.